# In Razor view MVC populate @HTML.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Not sure how to select textbox with jQuery and then populate that text box also will it be a problem saving that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "clsText" })
```

this will put an id of Text on the field and/or class clsText.  You can use either field to select on in jquery.  Any value that you set to the for helper will be passed back to the controller